# Many to many JPA, insert in table A and join table only if table B has entry

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, single-page-application

I have a many to many association between two tables, table A and B, and a Join table linking them:

[image]

Is there any way using JPA or DB Logic to post something in A and Join ONLY if B has certain entry??

Answer (score 1):

If A and B are Entities, you can use @PrePersist annotation.
Simply @PrePersit means Before Insert, so you can check the entries in B before inserting in A.

```
Class A{
int id;
String name;

@PrePersist
public void beforeInsert(){
//if B has certain entry
//then save in Join
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if B has certain entries while posting A. You can check that using the JPA repository methods of B.